# Magento error 404 after server move

Tags: magento

I hope someone here can help. I’ve spent days looking through forums and google results to no avail :( 
Basically I have a friend that was having a magento site developed for them, but the company doing the developing have been giving them the run around for over a year. Because of this, my friend has asked if I could move this onto my shared host to continue developing, and then once complete, to move onto their own VPS. 
Below is a list of things I have done:

1. Moved all files to shared host
2. imported .sql file into a new database
3. altered .xml to new database name and password etc
4. altered the database to point to the relevent IP address for
   developing instead of the previous development url (friend doesn’t
   own the url previously used)
5. deleted all cache and other temp
   files as per online instructions to moving magento.
6. reindexed cache and index management.

After doing this, the site loads fine, until I want to navigate into a category or product page etc, then I get a full screen 404, not magento’s 404. 
If I manually add index.php into the middle of the url, the page will load. If I disable the SEO rewrite then obviously everything works fine (other than any links that have been manually created into images etc of course). This lead me to believe it was a problem with rewrites, so I altered the rewrite url in .htaccess to point to google, and when I click on a category etc, that then indeed directs me to google. So I know the problem isn’t rewrites not working. 
I then found a site suggesting it could be a problem importing the database that replaced 0’s with 1’s in certain database locations, however I checked this and all is just as it should be.

I know everything was working fine before the move, as I was developing the site for my friend whilst it was on the original server (long story, people who were being payed to do things weren’t, so I was doing it, however they refused to give ftp access to be able to change faults in the skin)

Version of the magento concerned is 1.501

Also, I already have one magento install working successfully on my shared host, so I know the host is compatible with magento.

One further thing that I believe proves apache rewrites are working (I've been told a lot that they can't be!, I've even checked with the hosting company just to make ultra sure): 
If I amend the .htaccess from index.php to http://ip.ip.ip.ip/~example/index.php then the categories start to work!! 
However this isn’t a fix, because no matter what I cannot get other links to work, e.g: On a few pages I redirected the category to land at a “landing page” then there was a description and an image to then click to take you to the product page. These links now do NOT work!!!

If anyone can give me any ideas where I need to be looking I would greatly appreciate it.

Many thanks for reading.

Oh, and nothing comes up in the error log either.

Comment: I would suggest to rather delete or rename the local.xml in app/etc/ folder and install the magneto again... this might solve your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestion, however I've found the solution.
Magento obviously didn't like being run from the ip address followed by a folder. 
I've since assigned it a temporary domain name and everything is working 100%